# eBay API categoryId in findItemsAdvanced call returns wrong categories

Tags: ebay-api

I'm trying to use the `categoryId` in my `findItemsAdvanced` query:

```
api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {
         'keywords': 'laptop',
         'categoryId': '51148'}
```

The results I get are, for example (printing the `searchResult` dictionary):

```
'itemId': {'value': '200971548007'}, 'isMultiVariationListing': .............
'primaryCategory': {'categoryId': {'value': '69202'}, 'categoryName': {'value': 'Air Conditioning'}}  
....."
```

You can see that the result has a `categoryId` of 69202, and not 51148.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm just using the finding.py code at:

https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python

Thanks

---

**Edit**

I've done some tests. I extracted the XML that the SDK builds. If I call with:

```
'categoryId': '177'
```

The response is:

```
    the request_xml is  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><findItemsAdvancedRequest 
xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><categoryId>177</categoryId>
<itemFilter><name>Condition</name><value>Used</value></itemFilter><itemFilter>
<name>LocatedIn</name><value>GB</value></itemFilter><keywords>laptop</keywords>
<paginationInput><entriesPerPage>100</entriesPerPage><pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
</paginationInput></findItemsAdvancedRequest>
```

and I get the same with

```
'categoryId': ['177']
```

I find this a bit odd, I thought the appropriate name for the XML `categoryId` was 'CategoryId' with a capital C. If I do that I don't get an error, but the result is not restricted to the `categoryId` requested. 
Doing it like above, I still get the error:

> Exception: findItemsAdvanced: Domain: Marketplace, Severity: Error,
>   errorId: 3, Invalid category ID.

Comment: Try another. Lets get one working. Possibly your endpoint has different allowed categories.

Comment: I don't know if this will help but the category 51148 does not exist on the UK eBay site.

Comment: I try without the categoryId requirement and then I take one of the ones in the output, so it has to exist! In particular, I'm trying with 177, which corresponds to laptops and notebooks.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly the issue is? If you are using the category ID 51148  in any of your requests it will simply not work as this category is not valid for the UK site. If you are using the category 177 then as far as I can see the code should be ok.

Comment: If I don't use any categoryId requirement, and print the categoryIds that my search retrieves, I get 177, for example. Now I repeat the exact same search but I _only_ add 'categoryId': '177', which should be the way of getting results only for that category. Then it complains with the error I pasted above, "Invalid category ID." The categoryId is valid, I just got it from the previous search, so I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I've noticed that the finding.py example available at https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/samples/finding.py is searching the Belgium eBay site. If you are passing EBAY-NLBE in your code then it will fail as the category 177 does not exist in Belgium. I've add an example that shows how to search the UK site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will do a keyword search for 'laptops' across the UK eBay site and restrict the search to the two categories Apple Laptops(111422) and PC Laptops & Netbooks(177). In addition the results are filtered to only show the first 25 used items that are priced between £200 and £400. The results are also sorted by price from high to low.

There are a few things to keep in mind about this example.

- It assumes that you have already installed [ebaysdk-python](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python).
- According to the eBay [docs](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.categoryId) the categoryId field is a string and more than one category can be specified. An array is therefore used to hold the category ids that we are interested in.
- Our request needs to search for items in the UK eBay site. We therefore pass EBAY-GB as the siteid parameter.
- Category ids are different across each eBay site. For example the category PC Laptops & Netbooks(177) does not exist in Belgium. (Which incidently is the site that is used in the ebaysdk-python [finding.py](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/samples/finding.py) example.)

This example is also available as a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/davidtsadler/6993747)

```
import ebaysdk
from ebaysdk import finding

api = finding(siteid='EBAY-GB', appid='<REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN APPID>')

api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {
    'keywords': 'laptop',
    'categoryId' : ['177', '111422'],
    'itemFilter': [
        {'name': 'Condition', 'value': 'Used'},
        {'name': 'MinPrice', 'value': '200', 'paramName': 'Currency', 'paramValue': 'GBP'},
        {'name': 'MaxPrice', 'value': '400', 'paramName': 'Currency', 'paramValue': 'GBP'}
    ],
    'paginationInput': {
        'entriesPerPage': '25',
        'pageNumber': '1'
    },
    'sortOrder': 'CurrentPriceHighest'
})

dictstr = api.response_dict()

for item in dictstr['searchResult']['item']:
    print "ItemID: %s" % item['itemId'].value
    print "Title: %s" % item['title'].value
    print "CategoryID: %s" % item['primaryCategory']['categoryId'].value
```

I hope the following will explain why performing a search on the Belgium site results in items that contain the category 177 even though this is not valid for Belgium but is valid for the UK.

Basically eBay allow sellers from one site to appear in the search results of another site as long as they meet the required criteria, such as offering international shipping. It allows sellers to sell to other countries without the need to actually list on those sites.

From the example XML that elelias provided I can see that a keyword search for 'laptop' was made on the Belgium site with the results filtered so that only items located in the UK was to be returned.

```
<itemFilter>
    <name>LocatedIn</name>
    <value>GB</value>
</itemFilter>
```

Because the search was limited to those located in the UK you won't see any Belgium items in the results. Since the items where listed on the UK site they will contain information relevant to the UK. For example the category id 177. eBay does not convert the information to make it relevant to the site that you are searching on.

It is important to remember that what ever you are trying to do with the Finding API can also be repeated using the actual advance search on eBay. For example it is possible to re-create the issue by performing a keyword search for used items on the Belgium site.

This [url](http://www.benl.ebay.be/sch/i.html?_nkw=laptop&_in_kw=1&_ex_kw=&_sacat=0&_okw=&_oexkw=&_adv=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&LH_ItemCondition=4&_ftrt=901&_ftrv=1&_sabdlo=&_sabdhi=&_samilow=&_samihi=&_sadis=200&_fpos=&LH_SubLocation=1&_sargn=-1%26saslc%3D0&_fsradio2=%26LH_LocatedIn%3D1&_salic=3&_saact=23&LH_SALE_CURRENCY=0&_sop=12&_dmd=1&_ipg=50) is the equivalent of your code that was performing the search without specifying the category 177. As you can see from the results it returns items that where listed on the UK site but which are appearing in the Belgium site. It you click on some of the items, for [example](http://www.benl.ebay.be/itm/Panasonic-Toughbook-CF-18-Laptop-Pentium-M-1-1GHz-1-2GB-Ram-160GB-HDD-No-OS-/121188221073?pt=UK_Computing_Laptops_EH&hash=item1c37618091), you can even see that it displays the UK category PC Laptops & Netbooks (177) even though this does not exist on the Belgium site. This matches the results form your code where it was returning 177 but would not let you specify the same value in the request as you was searching the Belgium site.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much. It was a stupid thing, the parameter siteid in the ebaysdk example is set to 'EBAY-NLBE' for some reason. However, the funny thing is that a search DOES output the category '177', and yet trying to use that category in the filter makes the error happen again. Do you know why? Thanks again

Comment: I've updated my answer to hopefully explain the search results that you was getting.

Comment: That's a great in-depth answer, thanks a lot for your help again.

Answer (score 1):

Because categoryId is [repeatable](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/CallRef/findItemsAdvanced.html#Request.categoryId). You will need to pass an array into the call. Something like this should work.

```
api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', {
        'keywords': 'laptop',
        'categoryId': [
             {'51148'}
    ]
}
```

Note: See how the itemFilter element is an array in the [sample file](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/samples/finding.py) of the SDK.

```
'itemFilter': [
        {'name': 'Condition',
         'value': 'Used'},
        {'name': 'LocatedIn',
         'value': 'GB'},
    ],
```

Comment: nop, thanks for the answer, but that doesn't work either. Why should one have the Id between curly brackets? the itemFilter has a dictionary structure to provide the name and the value, but the categoryId should only have strings. I already tried with 'categoryId': ["51148"], also 'categoryId': [{'value': '51148'}], but nothing seems to work :(

Comment: Can you get the XML generated?